# Finding the order i add elements to a 2d array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

So i start with a matrix full of zeros, and i defined a struct called a Point, a point has the value i want to add and the index which the value is added. For example if the first element i add is 3.4 its index is 1, the next will be 2 and so on.

```
typedef struct 
{
int index;
double value;

}Point;



void adds(int line, int column, double value, Point matrix [100] [100] ){
static int c = 1;
matrix[line][column].value = value;
matrix[line][column].index = c;
c++;
}
```

There i have the struct and the method that adds a value to the line and column i want, i already tested and the index for the values are correct as i add them. I have a method that is supposed the print the values by crescent order of their index

```
void list(Point matrix [100][100]){

int i, j, c;

if(zeros(matrix) == 0)
    printf(" empty matrix\n");

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        for(c = 1; c <= nelem(matrix); c++){
           if( matrix[i][j].index == c)
              printf("[%d;%d] = %0.3lf\n", i, j, matrix[i][j].value);
         }

    }
}
```

}

I dont know why but this prints the values by order of lines and columns and not by index order and i cant figure out whats wrong, can anyone help me find out?

Comment: Hint 1: Your innermost `for` loop (on `c`) isn't doing anything except slowing down the program. Hint 2: When you exchange the nesting of the inner and outer loop you will find first that your program takes a long time to run, and next that the output is correct. You really need a different data structure which you can easily sort by index using a well-known sorting algorithm.

Comment: @TypeIA Im still new at C, this if for a project and we are not even supposed to use pointers yet. If i put the innermost `for` as the outer loop will the output be correct?

Comment: Impossible for me to say because you haven't posted your full code (see [mcve]) but it would appear so. Why don't you try it? And you can use the debugger to step through the code and _see_ what's happening - this is an absolutely indispensable tool that you should learn to use as soon as possible. Good luck!

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Answer (score 0):

Won't a `sort`:

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size, 
            int (*comparator)(const void*,const void*));
```

with a proper comparator function work:

```
qsort(matrix, 100*100, sizeof(matrix[0][0]), cmp);
```

The `cmp` will be:

```
int cmp(const void *a,const void *b)
{
  struct Point *a1 = (struct Point *)a;
  struct Point *a2 = (struct Point*)b;
  if((*a1).index>(*a2).index)return -1;
  else if((*a1).index<(*a2).index)return 1;
  else return 0;
}
```

---

**Comparator function** :

```
int comparator(const void* p1, const void* p2);
```

Return value meaning:

- <0 The element pointed by p1 goes before the element pointed by p2
- 0  The element pointed by p1 is equivalent to the element pointed by
  p2
- >0 The element pointed by p1 goes after the element pointed by p2